Should I change advisors because mine doesn't object to publishing at MDPI?
I am a CS PhD student who recently published a review paper in an MDPI journal, following my supervisor’s recommendation. After publishing, I learned from peers that MDPI is considered predatory. I researched online and found similar concerns.
Before publishing, I verified that the journal was Q1 and indexed, and I trusted my supervisor’s advice, unaware of MDPI’s reputation. Now, I am uncertain about my decision, as my supervisor often (not exclusively) publishes in MDPI, while other supervisors at my university avoid it. This has made me question my work and progress, which I was initially proud of.
I am now doubting whether my methods and ideas are good enough for reputable journals, and I worry that my supervisor’s name might not help in future publications. Additionally, I am concerned about my future opportunities, as I plan to pursue a post-PhD career and fear being turned down.
My question is, what should I do now? Should I look for another advisor or co-advisor? Should I continue and hope that my next publication will be accepted in reputable journals, considering my scholarship has time constraints? What should I do ?
Edit: As I mentioned in my initial questions, I am not debating whether MDPI is good or bad. Instead, I am aware that it has a questionable reputation. However, my supervisor doesn’t seem to share this view. Consequently, I am uncertain about whether I should continue working with him.

as this question is now, I think it is clearly not a duplicate. It is not asking about the reputation of MDPI, it is asking whethre a disagreement over that reputation is good cause to change supervisor. Voting against closure.

MDPI is a bit of a grey area. I personally would never publish there or review for them, but there are researchers I very much respect who do. I wouldn't put much trust in the peer-review at MDPI, but that doesn't mean that everything published there is rubbish. Based on what I've heard from other people, my impression is that views like mine are common.
For you, this means that you shouldn't worry about your paper being counted against you. The choice of journal of early-stage PhD students reflects much more on their supervisor than them. That your supervisor publishes quite a bit in MDPI journals might be a yellow flag regarding their overall reputation, but it is not a red flag.
You should definitely try and get some publications in other venues, but other than that I don't think you need to worry too much.

The question here seems to be "should I change advisors because they don't have problems with MDPI". Lets start by pointing our that MDPI is  not your typical "predactory publisher", in fact, as others (and answers in the linked question also say) have stated, there are quite a few very respected people that publish there, and in some fields, the MDPI journals are acutally quite high quality and offer a much faster possibility to be published due to their streamlined process compared to many other journals. So this is not black and white, but rather grey area territory. I would not be so quick to judge people incompetent just because the publish in MDPI journals. Almost everyone I know in my field has published there, mainly because in some interdisciplinary fields, it is not super easy to get published in more thematically rigid "more respectable" journals.
And just a short anecdote to add:
My advisor (who is a respected scholar in his field, head of a research instution, professor at a quality uni etc.) has in the past forwarded me invitations to publish of a much more shady nature than any MDPI journals. Have I found this questionable? Yes. But would I change an otherwise excellent advisor just because of such a minor faux-pas? Probably not.

MDPI is controversial. Some see it as problematic, while others see it as a respectable publisher. This probably varies by field; my experience and opinion is that the company has some poor practices, but that specific journals that they publish are well thought of in their fields.
(Note that I'm avoiding the word "predatory": MDPI is a real publisher that is not setting out to scam people; it just has some objectionable behaviours.)
I would not view a disagreement over the status of MDPI as a major obstable in a professional relationship. Changing advisors seems like an over-reaction.

There are excellent top-level researchers which have published good work in MDPI journals. There are massive differences in the quality of these journals, and some of them are definitively consistently capturing good work, even if their peer-review process is being viewed critically.
Some (very strong) authors I am aware of have become very critical of peer-review itself and welcome the existence of outlets which provide a sanity check rather than a gatekeeping role. Peer-review itself is now undergoing massive scrutiny (talking about "cult" around "peer-review as the only way", many retractions in top journals, an increasing litany of multiply rejected masterworks, the waste of time by having to accommodate unreasonable reviewer demands, only half-competent reviews, despite ostensibly for a top journal).
In short: nothing is absolute, everything needs to be judged by merit.
One thing you could do to reassure yourself is to see if that particular journal has other good authors or papers in its history, especially its recent one.
Furthermore, if your supervisor otherwise has publications in  established good journals, then this is not a reason to worry.
As a young researcher, just make sure you also get publications in other outlets that are high quality by consensus. It is generally a good idea to spread your publication portfolio, anyway, not only to avoid pigeonholing yourself, but also to make your work visible to other communities.

I have never heard peer-review described as being related to a cult.  A reference perhaps?

@TerryLoring It was a polemic contraction of several different discussions I had. To be sure, I kind of understand why people want peer review, even if I am critical of it. But sometimes one gets these people that uncritically consider it the only way to publish appropriately, and this feels almost like an unreflected religious belief. After all, it used to be optional in the past (Einstein almost never had any of his papers peer reviewed, and surely he was not the only one with this privilege; community probably switched to peer review due to US-centric view of how publications should run)

First, relax. You've drawn inferences well beyond what can be drawn. Furthermore, one paper does not make or break your academic career or PhD.
Next, because you are encountering predatory publishing for the first time, you probably don't understand the topic well enough to make informed conclusions. Some food for thought:

Isn't predatory publishing supposed to produce red flags during peer review? Did you see any red flags? If yes, how is it that you didn't realize it was predatory until after your paper was published? If no, how can you be sure it's predatory?
Let's take the worst-case scenario which seems to be implied in your question: your supervisor is an imposter who got to where they are only because they published a bunch of fake papers at a predatory publisher. Does this imply that your department/university are also unaware that MDPI is predatory? How probable is it that all of the professors at your department/university are unaware?
Furthermore, if they really are all unaware, does that imply that you'll have no special difficulty getting a post-PhD academic job because other departments/universities are probably also unaware that MDPI is predatory?

Hopefully the above shows that it's likely that your supervisor is aware of the issues with MDPI, and they chose to publish there anyway. That suggests that there's something important you don't know. (See this question for more information about the complexity surrounding MDPI.)
The last step is to talk to your supervisor about why they chose to publish with MDPI anyway. It's possible they're unaware of the issues with MDPI, but don't assume it. Tell them instead that you're concerned about MDPI's reputation, and that publishing the paper there might've damaged your standing. See what he says. He'll probably give you a set of reasons why he thinks your concerns are misplaced.
After taking those into consideration, if you still believe your concerns are correct, you can refuse to publish in MDPI journals in the future. Because all authors must agree to publish with a journal before the journal can publish it, if you stand your ground, you can force the paper to not be published. Of course, this will damage your relationship with your supervisor - but cross the bridge when you get there.

Are you still employed at MDPI? If so, the first sentence in this answer must be a disclosure of this obvious conflict of interest. Please edit your answer to disclose this current or past conflict.

I'm not going to force an edit, but I think answerers have an ethical obligation to disclose conflicts of interest that include current and past employment, and it seems legitimate to point out with a comment when such disclosure is known to be absent.

It seems easiest to me to proactively write "disclosure: I used to work for MDPI". We don't need details of when or explanations of why you don't work there now. It doesn't mean the answer needs to necessarily be either pro- or anti-MDPI, it's just to provide readers with context. And I don't think it's necessary when discussing publishing procedures more generally.

No, you should not change advisors because of this.  Aside from any controversy about the journal in question, unless your advisor is forcing you to publish in journals that you have a major problem with, changing your advisor because of this seems like a major overreaction to me, like killing a mosquito with a shotgun.

I don’t believe changing advisors over this issue is necessary. I suggest discussing your concerns with them, so you can both evaluate the pros and cons of publishing in MDPI. Most likely, the impact of the journal on their career is relatively small compared to the potential impact on yours, so advisors are usually flexible in such matters.
